# How do you comment out a block of text in the vhosts file?

Tags: vhosts

How do you comment out a block of text in the vhosts file?

Do I have to put pound/hash symbols (#) in front of EVERY line?

Comment: Most decent text editors should be able to do that easily.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you will have to put pound/hash symbols (`#`) in front of ALL the lines you want commented out. There are no 'block comments' tag/symbols.

Some text editors have column-mode editing, which means you can select multiple lines and edit text in all of them at the same time. You can use this feature to insert the `#` symbol in front of the lines you selected.

Answer (score 26):

This is not a solution but a workaround. You can put the code you want to comment inside an *IfDefine* block, so it will be ignored unless a dumb variable is defined:

```
<IfDefine IgnoreBlockComment>
...
</IfDefine>
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/414428